# My hop-up makes BBs turn to the side. How can I fix it?

Tags: maintenance, airsoft

I've noticed the hop-up of my AEG AK47 Beta twists my BBs sideways. The accuracy at short range (10m) is quite good but at 30+ meters the aim is a good meter off the mark to the right and only deteriorates more with distance.

The hop-up rubber has been replaced but the problem persists. What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check your barrel for scratches (replace it if you find any)
2. Clean your barrel
3. Rotate the barrel a little bit
4. Try using heavier balls

If it doesn't help, try using elastic (silicon) hop-up rubber